# Several ports required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost are already in use

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

Tried changing the ports but error still persists. 
We have used Windows 2008, 8.1, 7 with just java, tomcat, and eclipse installed to isolate the problem but no luck.
We don't know where to get the logs for more information regarding this error.
I am not a programmer just helping my colleague.

Link below is the netstat result as well as the server.xml file:
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8s89SzGxv2Xclp3bllKTzloZ0E/view?usp=sharing

Guys any idea on how we can troubleshoot and know the exact issue for this?

Comment: Have a look here to find out what ports your Tomcat is trying to use: https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/

Comment: Maybe you are starting two tomcats in parallel? One from within eclipse and another from the console? If you do this, the ports obviously are already in use when you start the second tomcat.

Comment: @NiklasP Or another Tomcat is still running in the background.

Comment: @Niklas We did not install tomcat.. We have point the eclipse to the tomcat zip file located at drive C (root). I also make sure to execute the shutdown.bat just to make sure no tomcat is running.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the requirement you can change or add new port in tomcat.

edit server.xml file which is located at conf folder.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>

<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: I think we already did this.. Can you confirm the file I have shared on google drive?